How to config "Auto Generate NanoID" like UUID in Entity Class
i don't know config auto generate NanoID in entity class like UUID
Example config UUID in Manager class:
@Entity
public class Manager {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid2")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid2", strategy = "uuid2")
    @Column(name = "id")
    private UUID id;
}

I try to search about config auto generate auto Id by nanoId but i don't see what i want T_T. Can everyone help me
